# Hosted IMAP webmail client

Tags: web-apps, email-client, hosted, imap

I'm looking for a hosted IMAP webmail client with (at least) the following features:

- supports for multiple accounts (gmail and custom domains)
- great support for rules (even for already received emails!)
- good support for searches/filters
- able to manage IMAP folders
- responsive and clean design for use from both desktop and mobile browsers
- compatible with Firefox
- annual cost < 100 USD

Looking at older questions and doing searches on Google I can find only self-hosted application (right now I'm not interested) or services provided by hosting plans (with new email addresses, etc...).

I need only a "reader", I already have the emails account and I don't need features like backups or storages (i.e. Zoho Mail).

I may accept to stay with gmail but they seem to refuse to allow users to add non-gmail IMAP accounts easily...

Comment: Not sure if it fits all your criteria, but Nextcloud has multiple mail applications ([RainLoop](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/rainloop), [Mail](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/mail), [Roundcubemail](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/roundcubemail)) – and there are providers offering you a Nextcloud instance for a small fee permitting apps to be installed.

Comment: @Izzy I did something similar with a VPS where I installed some applications. It's still a good option, but right now I'm looking for something ready to use. Furthermore in my experience when someone offers too much services, they cannot be so well-developed...